References/Database for commonly used quotes
I stumbled upon a quote that is said to be by Einstein: "Je mehr ich weiß, desto mehr erkenne ich, dass ich nichts weiß." ("The more I know, the more I realize that i know nothing") which was him rephrasing a quote that is said to be by Platon. I would like to verify that this is correctly attributed to Einstein but so far I had no luck. Is there a database or a common practice when trying this in e.g. sciences like history, anthropology and/or philosophy to check for such things?
In my search for the origin I found several rephrased versions of this but no reference to any source and I know that wrongly attributing such things to famous people happens. I found that the original quote by Platon (translated to German) actually is „Denn von mir selbst wusste ich, dass ich gar nichts weiß ...“ (Platon: Apologie des Sokrates translated by Friedrich Schleiermacher "Because, of myself I knew, that I know nothing...") which also often is abreviated or permuted when used as a quote. I searched a digitized archive (https://albert-einstein.huji.ac.il/) but also found nothing (I guess for many of their scans of letters and protocols the body of text is not searchable so it might be in there but not extractable easily).
I also asked a friend who is a doctoral student in philosophy (my field is engineering) how he would go about it and he told me that what I am trying to do can be really tricky and that he once spend several days searching to verify a quote of some semi-well known philosopher. He still encouraged me to ask on the internet since people from other fields might know of a data-set that he does not know since he has no (regular) use for it, especially since the specific quote I am trying to verify is by a very well known scientist which might increase my chances of finding something.
EDIT: Thank you for your comments and and answers so far. Since I posted the question I did some further digging and there are such data-bases, at least for e.g. Platon which also use a special numbering system for referencing the quotes. There also is a wikiquote (https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) for Einstein which of course is not to be trusted blindly, but it has some references to some trustworthy sources that could be checked further. I did not find the quote directly but there is the following paragraph under the "misattributed" section for the quote "A little knowledge is a dangerous thing. So is a lot.": "... But long before that, the same quote appears in an advertisement for Encyclopaedia Britannica that ran in The Atlantic Monthly: Volume 216 from 1965, p. 139. The ad mentioned Einstein but did not directly attribute the quote to him: "Encyclopaedia Britannica says: A little knowledge is a dangerous thing. So is a lot. The more you know, the more you need to know — as Albert Einstein, for one, might have told you. ..." This is close and could be the cause for attributing it to him but that of course is a guess at best. Did not find anything more concrete.
Still I guess wikiquotes could be a first good stop to check for such things in the future. Just wanted to share this finding.
EDIT 2: I found the book "The Ultimate Quotable Einstein" which is a compilation of Einstein quotes with references for each one. Several full-text searches came up with nothing. I guess the chance of the quote indeed being apocryphal is growing. Sidenote: Interesting short article on several (other) quotes wrongly attributed to Einstein (https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05004-4).

Asking for a database may be judged off-topic here (and I don't think this exists). Asking for a process is more likely to be kept open. I personally once tried to find the source for Box' "all models are wrong. but some are useful" and simply Googled my way until I found a definite attribution, then went to the library and looked it up in the paper book, and finally cited the exact book and page number in a paper.

The process you describe is more or less how I do it for other things as well. I do not get why it would be off-topic though to ask for a commonly used data-base. If I would be asked for a data-base of publications I would also recommend e.g. checking google scholar which is widely used in the process of finding relevant publications. Not trying to be smart or anything I just honestly do not get the issue which is probably due to me being new to the academia section of stack exchange.

This isn’t really about academia, is it? I mean, yes, you need it in the context of academia but it would be exactly the same in the context of, say, vetting clever postcards (I do incidentally have one with an "Einstein quote" right next to me).

Ok thank you for clarifying that. I get the point now and i think it is actually a fair point to make. I considered it not to be off-topic since i thought it to be quite similar to e.g. finding citation material in the form of paragraphs/equations in a book/article which I would argue is a standard academic practice. What would you suggest? Should I delete the topic?

In the old days, there were books of quotations ("Bartlett's Familiar Quotations", "Oxford Compendium  ..." if I remember correctly), and the particular Einstein/Plato quote should be there. I imagine these books now exist as databases and you may have already  checked them, but if not then they  might be worth a try.

I unfortunately do not have access to either of these books through my university library but a digital searchable version of these would indeed be a great resource for the task of verifying quotes. In the meantime I found a quotations book with Einstein quotes and searched it. I updated my question accordingly.

You could buy a paper copy of one of those books that @AndreasBlass mentioned. They are searchable as you can look up Einstein or a keyword like knowledge in the index.

I know of no such database and would hardly trust it if it exists. Who is to judge whether the contents of such a database are true, definitively? As you have found, that can be exceedingly hard.
Note that some such "quotes" are apocryphal. Note that the "speakers" of some such things were actually quoting or paraphrasing other earlier statements and so, while they may indeed have said something in particular, they aren't the actual source.
As you have found, there is disagreement among sources as to the source of some "quotes". The problem is difficult in general and the older the "quote" the harder it can get.
I've run in to the problem myself, sometimes in answering questions here. When an internet search yields non-definitive results, I tend to mark such quotes as, for example, "attributed to Einstein...". Sometimes that is the best one can do. Trust, but verify [Russian proverb, sometimes attributed to Ronald Reagan].

Thank you for your answer. I mostly agree and the "attributed to ..." method is a good idea. However, I would feel like I did my due diligence if I checked the references given in such a database if existent and would have no issue attributing the quote directly to (in this case) Einstein and depending on context citing the source. FYI: I also updated my question above with some new findings. On wikiquotes I even found the misattributed Reagan quote you gave in your answer (with no direct citation of serious source material though) :)

If the database included citations of courses, that would show whether it was true

@toby544, no, it would show that someone "thought" it was true, not whether someone said something, but whether that was the original source of the quote. That is much harder.

@Buffy If there would be e.g. a lecture transcript including the quote, would you not consider it to be fine to use the quote referencing the transcript even if an earlier documented occurence might exist somewhere? It is always good to quote first appearances of an idea, but e.g. in my field often it is fine to just cite e.g. a paper with the respective equation used. Then again I can see how, taken to the silly extreme, I could record a video of mine saying "veni, vidi, vici" and use the phrase, attributing it to me. I guess it might come down to the question of who popularized a quote then?

@Ben, it depends on whether you need the first use or not.

@Buffy Agreed. Though I guess proving someone was the first to say something is, as you said, harder (I would even argue "proving" it is close to impossible). So I would probably roughly go with "a person/group provably (within reason) said and/or wrote it and is considered to be the first person/group that is on record to do so".

Ask your librarian if they have a Dictionary of Quotations. Surely they will. If not, they may well be able to point you towards more specific resources about Einstein or Plato for your particular example.

This website might be useful. It is not a database but a blog where each entry is about one quote and the writer investigates who said it, and gives citations of books, old newspapers, etc.
https://quoteinvestigator.com/
I don't think it has your quote that is attributed to Einstein, but you could submit that as a question and perhaps the person would investigate it.

Thank you for your answer. I already found this website yesterday and searched the Einstein-related articles. I did not consider asking them directly if they could investigate it. They actually encourage sending in requests, but also state that they have several thousands of open investigations. I think I will write them. If for nothing else, maybe some of my findings can be added to an existing open case in their database.
